# Hosting angular 8 app on a Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-zero

I installed **node.js**, **npm** and **angular-cli**.

My intention is to host an angular 8 app on the raspberry-pi which I can view from other devices.

So, I execute `ng new test-app`, change into the test-app directory and then `ng serve` to begin serving the simple app.

However, when I visit `http:192.*.*.12:4200`, I get the following message:

> This site can’t be reached

I need help understanding why this isn't working and how I can make it work, please.

Comment: Why don't you use `apache2` package to host your Angular web app?

Comment: @M.Rostami: could you recommend a tutorial, please?

Comment: This can be an issue with webserver config, but there can be other issues as well. `serve` as well as `apache` should be accessible. Is both the devices in same network? If yes, is the IP correct? Can you connect via SSH? If yes, then the webserver might be blocking the request.

Answer (score 2):

You can host an Angular web app by `apache` package. You need to export the project then copy data on the default path of `apache`.

---

### Installation

Install the `apache`:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Enable/Start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2

sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

Now, you can check the default page of `apache` by opening `127.0.0.1` or the hostname/IP address of the raspberry pi on the browser.

Default path:

```
/var/www/html/
```

Every web page you put will be accessible over your root domain or IP address.

As an example, we made a directory named `khar` (full path is `/var/www/html/khar`) create a simple `gav.html` file (full path is `/var/www/html/khar/gav.html`). This page would be accessible on `127.0.0.1/khar/gav.html` on the browser.

All you need is that getting an export of your Angular page and copy all the files on `/var/www/html/`.

---

### Configuration

If you want to change the ports, change the `Listen` section of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` config file. Also, there are many more ways to change the configuration and default port.

---

***References:***

- [How to Change Apache HTTP Port](https://www.tecmint.com/change-apache-port-in-linux/)
- [How To Change Apache Default Port To A Custom Port](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-change-apache-ftp-and-ssh-default-port-to-a-custom-port-part-1/)
- [How to run angular 2 application on apache hosting server](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11884)

Comment: Thanks for this but can you explain what you mean by "export the project"? Do you mean moving the entire angular app into /var/www/html ?

Comment: @sisko Yes, the HTML, JS, CSS, etc files and directory.

Comment: @sisko Since you already have Node, I suggest you create a webserver using `express`. It will take only less than 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

M. Rostami  has given all the steps clearly, but for me the deployment had to be   `/var/www/khar` which gave the url as `http://localhost/khar/` .

Other than that after after `npm run build` in the `index.html` file replace `<base href="/">` with `<base href="./">` before copying to `/var/www/` directory.

Comment: If you are deploying in a sub folder you can specify that during build with command `ng build --base-href=/your-sub-folder-name/
`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to run the app for testing using **ng serve** command, you can only view your app in http://localhost:4200/.

If you'd like to view your app using the IP of your server in your network like http://192.168.1.1:4200/, you'll need to run **ng serve --host 192.168.1.1**

But note that, you may only do so for testing purposes.

Hope that helps!